# Replace not working with SAP Gui Scripting retrieved data

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

So I created a scripting to retrieve data from SAP Gridview object to an Excel sheet. Some columns I needed to replace some characters because this data is consumed by a Power Bi report. For example:

4,350.00 will be replaced for the value 4350. So I do two replaces, the first removing the . and the second replacing the , with .

The problem is that the replace is being applied in every data retrieved. Here's the code.

```
For i = 0 To GridView.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To GridView.ColumnCount - 1
            shtInput.Cells(z + i, j + 1) = GridView.GetCellValue(i, GridView.ColumnOrder(j))
                If j > 8 And j < 19 Then:
                    rep = GridView.GetCellValue(i, GridView.ColumnOrder(j))
                    rep = replace(rep, ".", "")
                    rep = replace(rep, ",", ".")
                    shtInput.Cells(z + i, j + 1) = rep
        Next j
            shtInput.Cells(z + i, Area) = "Finance"
        If i Mod 32 = 0 Then
            GridView.SetCurrentCell i, CStr(Columns(0))
            GridView.firstVisibleRow = i
        End If
    Next i
```

There's a data column that the script capture the value 21.02.2021 and replace it with 21,02,2021.

Comment: Is the `4,350.00` a String? Or is it a number and you simply need to change the number format?

Comment: The cell says "General" so I guess that it's a String. When I use the SAP Export data function and open the excel it comes as a number with the raw value as 5350 formated as 4,350.00